# Добавление namespace в сообщение

Tags: c#, wcf

Есть веб-служба, которая принимает сообщения вида:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <purchases>
                /../
        </purchases>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

В объект `purchases` надо добавить свое пространство имен, чтобы сообщение приняло следующий вид:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <purchases xmlns:t1="mynamespace">
                /../
        </purchases>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Нашел, что это можно сделать [через форматтер сообщения](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/apr/02/custom-message-formatting-in-wcf-to-add-all-namespaces-to-the-soap-envelope), но код выглядит достаточно объемным для такой задач. Есть ли способы проще?

Comment: Опишите подробнее. Я так понимаю, под словами "веб-служба" имеется в виду web service asmx? Он выставляет файл описания? По нему должны генерироваться классы со всему нужными неймспейсами.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Веб-сервис, написанный средствами Java. Клиент сгенерирован по wsdl, но при отправке сообщений нужно добавлять namespace ибо реализация сервиса кривая и ожидает получение сообщения только с некоторым пространством имен. Изменить сам сервис нет возможности.